# Uploading a JPEG image via Django displays error

Tags: django, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I'm running a Django app inside a virtualenv on Ubuntu with NGINX/FastCGI and trying to upload a JPG image to the Django admin app.

I'm getting this error: "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image." I can upload a GIF image, so it's only JPEG that's causing the problem.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1) Install libjpeg62-dev before PIL

```
pip uninstall pil
sudo apt-get libjpeg62-dev
pip install pil
```

At the end of the PIL install, I see:

```
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
              [GCC 4.4.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
```

So it looks like JPEG support is there. I've also done the manual test to verify and it verified:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> trial_image=Image.open("/path/to/my/image.png")
>>> trial_image.verify()
```

2) Similar to approach #1 above, but manually specifying the JPG_ROOT:

```
pip uninstall pil
sudo apt-get libjpeg62-dev
pip install --no-install pil
vi /path/to/virtualenv/build/PIL/setup.py (JPG_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/lib"))
pip install pil
```

3) Try my luck with Pillow (a PIL fork)

```
pip uninstall pil
sudo apt-get libjpeg62-dev
pip install pillow
```

I'm running Django under I've also trying stopping & starting the nginx service after each time installing PIL.

So far none of the above approaches have gotten me past the above error message in my Django app on Ubuntu. I can upload the same JPG image just fine on my local dev box (Mac OSX 10.6.5) running the same Django app, so I know it's something with my deployment on Ubuntu.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what do you know, I decided to log out of the Django admin and log back in....suddenly it works fine! Sheesh. The last thing I tried was approach #2 above so if anyone is having this problem, that's your best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. But the library required was different.

The answer, helped me, is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23445746/1478569